# Unable to set python3 as default on cloud9 using virtualenv

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv, aws-cloud9

I'm using AWS cloud9 and am having trouble switching from python2 (which is default when you create an environment) to python3. My goal is to run a flask app and have it run in python3.

I've tried using virutalenv like so:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python36 vpy36
source vpy36/bin/activate      
python --version
```

After doing this the python version is still listed as 2.7.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help much appreciated.